# cell alignment in Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Hi I have a grid I'm trying to style. A skin was provided for me which contains:

```
#tblPageContent td
{
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
   vertical-align:top;
   text-align:left;
}
```

This is used to style other elements in the web application so I can't remove this.

The problem is this is styling my grid items to all be align left. I actually want them centered.

I tried to override this by adding a class to my grid and setting:

```
.myRadGridClass
{
   text-align="center;
}
```

and

```
#myRadGrid td
{
   text-align:center;
}
```

However this is not working right now.

Can someone please help me to get the grid cells centered without removing the skin css?

Comment: Not a solution but i think                                 #myRadGrid td
{
   text-align:center;
}
is incorrect you cant use # in class names

Comment: That not the class name it's the grid id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to be more specific than the rule that's already defined.

I imagine that the HTML code generated looks like this :

```
<table id="tblPageContent">
    <tr>
        <td class="myRadGridClass">Content of your cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you go with the following css it should work :

```
#tblPageContent td.myRadGridClass
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

If the HTML code doesn't look like this, post a snippet and we'll be able to help you out.